# Undefined function '' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

i have already spent more than 5 hours trying to solve the problem on myself, but i guess im too stupid to do so. Here is the Code:

```
classdef valueInt
   properties
      myValue=0;
      PropertyName=0;
   end
   methods
      function v =  valueInt(val)
         v.myValue=val;
      end

       function obj = set.PropertyName(obj,value)

      obj.PropertyName = value;

        end

   end

end
```

I am getting `Undefined function 'PropertyName' for input arguments of type 'double'.` when i try in the Command: `objeect=PropertyName(2) or vi1=valueInt(7);`

Thank you for your help and time. My file is called "`valueInt`"

Comment: `object=PropertyName(2)` isn't supposed to work.  `valueInt` is the name of the class, and is also the name of the constructor, to create a new object.  `v1i=valueInt(7)` works for me with the same code.

Comment: Access properties using dot notation after instantiating the object. e.g. v1i = valueInt(7); v1i.PropertyName

Answer (score 0):

If you modify a MATLAB class, the modification don't come into effect immediately.

In order to make them effective, you have to reload the class. This is done with

```
clear classes
```

which only works if there are no class instances active.